# Module Adminhtml blocks not loading

Tags: magento, wysiwyg, block

I was working on a Magento module and it was working fine. At some point, I was trying to enable WYSIWYG in an edit form 'content' field and suddenly, my adminhtml grid and edit blocks stopped being generated. On my system are TinyMCE and Fontis FCKEditor WYSIWYG editors extensions. I'm not sure what I did wrong but my adminhtml blocks will no longer generate.

Here's a dump of all the blocks from my module's adminhtml layout:

```
    array(17) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "root"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "head"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "head.calendar"
  [3]=>
  string(14) "global_notices"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "header"
  [5]=>
  string(4) "menu"
  [6]=>
  string(11) "breadcrumbs"
  [7]=>
  string(7) "formkey"
  [8]=>
  string(12) "js_translate"
  [9]=>
  string(4) "left"
  [10]=>
  string(7) "content"
  [11]=>
  string(8) "messages"
  [12]=>
  string(2) "js"
  [13]=>
  string(6) "footer"
  [14]=>
  string(8) "profiler"
  [15]=>
  string(15) "before_body_end"
  [16]=>
  string(7) "wysiwyg"
}
```

As you can see, the last item is "wysiwyg" but on the layout output of other magento modules, there are more blocks. For example, on MathieuF's calendar extension, these are all the layout blocks:

```
array(26) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "root"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "head"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "head.calendar"
  [3]=>
  string(14) "global_notices"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "header"
  [5]=>
  string(4) "menu"
  [6]=>
  string(11) "breadcrumbs"
  [7]=>
  string(7) "formkey"
  [8]=>
  string(12) "js_translate"
  [9]=>
  string(4) "left"
  [10]=>
  string(7) "content"
  [11]=>
  string(8) "messages"
  [12]=>
  string(2) "js"
  [13]=>
  string(6) "footer"
  [14]=>
  string(8) "profiler"
  [15]=>
  string(15) "before_body_end"
  [16]=>
  string(7) "wysiwyg"
  [17]=>
  string(27) "adminhtml_event.grid.child0"
  [18]=>
  string(12) "ANONYMOUS_19"
  [19]=>
  string(27) "adminhtml_event.grid.child1"
  [20]=>
  string(12) "ANONYMOUS_21"
  [21]=>
  string(27) "adminhtml_event.grid.child2"
  [22]=>
  string(20) "adminhtml_event.grid"
  [23]=>
  string(12) "ANONYMOUS_24"
  [24]=>
  string(19) "ANONYMOUS_17.child1"
  [25]=>
  string(14) "content.child0"
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong? I've already tried Alan Storm's Layout and Config Viewers and cannot find any clues as to what I did wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If some block fails to render it may not to show any warning message just stop rendering process. So all looks fine, but your block isn't rendered. You should investigate your block's rendering process step by step and I'm sure in some point you'll find that it just fails.

Comment: Found my problem. I accidentally deleted the xml in the adminhtml layout for the module. Boy, took three weeks to figure out.